# dplyr mutate using value from a subset of separate data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Given the following two example data frames:

```
set.seed(2299)
df1 <- data.frame(site = c("site1","site1","site1","site2","site2","site2"),
                  A0 = rnorm(6),B0 = rnorm(6))
df2 <- data.frame(site = c("site1", "site2"),
                  A0dir = c(220, 110), B0dir = c(310,200))
```

How can I use the `A0dir` value from `df2` where the `df2$site == df1$site` in the row I am mutating with dplyr?

The following does not work.

```
df1 %>% 
      mutate(disp = df2$A0dir[site == df2$site] + A0/B0)
```

The following gets the right answer for `"site1"`, but I need it to work for all sites.

```
df1 %>% 
      mutate(disp = df2$A0dir["site1" == df2$site] + A0/B0)
```

Both the following produces `Error: not compatible with STRSXP`

```
df1 %>% 
      mutate(disp = subset(df2, site == .$site, select = A0dir))    

df1 %>% 
      mutate(disp = subset(df2, site == "site1", select = A0dir))
```

In reality, `df1` is much larger and I am trying to avoid completing a join to bring in the `A0dir` and `B0dir` variables from `df2` into `df1`.

Comment: Or `df1 %>% left_join(df2) %>% mutate(disp = A0dir + A0/B0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `match()` inside `mutate()`.

```
df1 %>% mutate(disp = df2$A0dir[match(site, df2$site)] + A0/B0)
#   site         A0         B0     disp
#1 site1 -1.5784780  0.1712790 210.7842
#2 site1  1.0957047  0.6394951 221.7134
#3 site1 -1.3443118  0.1814845 212.5927
#4 site2  1.0674512  0.7809774 111.3668
#5 site2  1.3821173  1.7001376 110.8129
#6 site2 -0.1283199 -0.7093244 110.1809
```

Comment: Worked great! thanks mtoto.  Also worked with multiple matches using `paste()`.